# Is it possible to simultaneously adjust the cache settings for multiple objects?

Tags: physics, baking, soft-body, cache

For example, changing the start and end of a simulation for multiple objects with soft-body physics applied.

Changing this:

[image]

Would change the cache settings for SoftBody.1, SoftBody.2, SoftBody.3 (which could all have different soft-body settings).

Comment: can you show me where this board is open

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with two solutions.

(1) **If the physics settings are the same for all objects:**

Change the cache settings for one object, then link the modifier to all other objects using `Make Links > Modifiers` (Hotkey `CTRL + L`)

(2) **If the physics settings are different:**

Use Python (Blender 2.8):

```
import bpy

# get objects in selection
for obj in bpy.context.collection.all_objects:
    if obj.modifiers:
        for modifier in obj.modifiers:
            if modifier.type == "SOFT_BODY":
                # adjust range here
                modifier.point_cache.frame_start = 1
                modifier.point_cache.frame_end = 3000
```